# Font taking to lot of to load what is the best way to load font fast while call via CDN

Tags: css

best way to load font fast while call via CDN

```
 @font-face{font-family:'proxima-nova';src:url('xxxxxxxxxxxx/proximanovaRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('xxxxxxxxxxxx/proximanovaRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('xxxxxxxxxxxx/proximanovaRegular.woff') format('woff'),
url('xxxxxxxxxxxx/proximanovaRegular.svg#proxima-nova') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal
}
```